# Unable to read from minio using spark due to "NoAuthWithAWSException: Credentials requested after provider list was closed"

Tags: java, apache-spark, minio

Here's the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("test")
            .set("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore")
            .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://localhost:9000")
            .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "minio")
            .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "minio123")
            .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
            .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
            .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
            ;

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local")
            .config(sparkConf)
            .getOrCreate();

    System.out.println("********** Reading from minio **********");
    Dataset<Row> csv = sparkSession
            .read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header","true")
            .csv("s3a://spark-test/test.csv")
            ;

    System.out.println("********** Writing to minio **********");
    csv.write().mode("overwrite").format("delta").save("s3a://spark-test/deltafile");
```

This is the output and hangs

```
********** Reading from minio **********
23/05/16 20:07:00 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
23/05/16 20:07:00 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/C:/<...>/spark-warehouse'.
23/05/16 20:07:02 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
23/05/16 20:07:02 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
23/05/16 20:07:02 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started
23/05/16 20:07:11 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
```

If I wait about 5 minutes and stop the program, I get this output with no errors:

```
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://BAH5CD010DT15.resource.ds.bah.com:4041
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\611528\AppData\Local\Temp\1\spark-9f08dab0-3643-4cec-9d40-443b5db388be
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
23/05/16 20:11:53 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.
```

But if I stop the program at the hanging point after only a minute, I get these additional messages:

```
23/05/16 20:13:26 WARN AWSCredentialProviderList: Credentials requested after provider list was closed
23/05/16 20:13:26 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: s3a://spark-test/test.csv.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://spark-test/test.csv: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: Credentials requested after provider list was closed
```

I've spent all day looking at this and haven't found a solution yet. It never even makes it to the write() portion of the code.  It's hanging on the read() for some reason.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out.  Because minio was running in a container, I had to do port forwarding so my test could reach minio.

Example:

kubectl port-forward -n gossamer-windows deployment/minio-deployment 9001:9000

Once I did the port forwarding I was able to read and right to minio in delta format.